# High frequency and received signal power? Why using massive MiMo?

Tags: signal-power, signal-energy, mimo

The power received by an isotrapic antenna is calculated by:

$P_0=\frac{P_T}{4 \pi d^2}\cdot \frac{\lambda^2}{4 \pi} = \frac{P_T}{4 \pi d^2}\cdot A_e$

or, by Friis transmission formula:

$\frac{P_r}{P_t} = \frac{A_r A_t}{d^2 \lambda^2}$

It is getting obvious, that with high frequencies my effective area becomes much smaller, and so my received power. Massive MiMo is used, because I can not emit enough energy by using a signal very small antenna? However, often people say high frequency carries a lot of energy? How does this relate to each other?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how "high frequency carries a lot of energy"?

Answer (score 2):

Massive MIMO is not related to received power and its decrease with increasing frequency. The point of massive MIMO is that the diversity order is huge, and the equations for receiver processing converge to tractable forms.

The ideas behind masive MIMO work at any (reasonable) RF frequency. However, very high frequencies allow for very small antennas, so that massive arrays become feasible to build and install in practice.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that "high frequency carries a lot of energy". See [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/425653/why-do-high-frequency-waves-have-high-energy) and [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33537/why-do-higher-frequency-waves-have-better-penetration).

The story of Massive MIMO unfolded as we people look for a way to dramatically increase communication throughput. The straightfoward approach is to use more bandwidth that can be found abundantly at high frequencies.

As the dimensions of antenna scale with the frequency, the higher the frequency, the smaller the energy captured by the antenna. We can keep the antenna size unchanged to capture the same energy, but this is only true if the antenne is well directed to the direction of signal, which is pratically impossible because the LoS links are not always available.

There are also other factors such as high atmospheric attenuation and less diffraction that reduce the reliablity of both LoS and NLoS links.

The problem is solved if we can compensate the high attenuation and steer signal to the desired direction. Massive MIMO offers both, especially in high frequencies that allow small antenna size as mentionned in [the answer of MBaz](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/81839/26081). Being directional, Massive MIMO also reduces interference, making it perfect solution for terrestrial high frequency communications.